# Installed KDE onto Xubuntu 12.04, now get black screen after login!

Tags: xubuntu, kde

I have a Panasonic Toughbook CF-19 MK3 that I recently installed Xubuntu 12.04 LTS on. That install went smoothly and works fine. Was looking for more customization, so decided to try KDE desktop. Used apt-get to install KDE 4.8.5. Everything was working fine after install until I rebooted; once I did that I had login issues (couldn't login, but was using KDE login manager - switched it back to XFCE login manager and that was solved).

Once I was able to login to a KDE session, I got this issue: as soon as I tough ANY key on the keyboard OR the touchpad, the screen goes black for a while. Eventually it comes back, but goes black upon key press/touchpad use. I tried editing the compositing line in the .kde/share/config/kwinrc file to Enabled=false, then rebooted, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

I've spent about 2 hours searching for answers on the internet, but I have not been able to find a solution. Anyone have any ideas? I want to try KDE, but this is frustrating! I'm relatively new to Linux also, and I'm trying to use Linux exclusively now (no Windows!)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answers your question, but if your end goal is to try KDE, why not install [Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/) directly. That is, Ubuntu with the KDE desktop environment. Especially if you are a new user installing Kubuntu is easier than installing another distro with KDE on top.

You will find that Kubuntu 13.10 comes with KDE version 4.11.2, so you will get the best of the KDE experience!

Comment: Are you saying to install Kubuntu fresh (erasing my hard drive in the process) or alongside my current Xubuntu install?